# Specify TCP port communication between a ROS node and a none ROS exe

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I have currently a software which is a black box! I can only connect to it through TCP/IP in localhost port 5000.
My question is very simple : How can I create a node in which I could create a connection to the port 5000 in localhost ? Do you have a sample which do this stuff ?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67171/specify-tcp-port-communication-between-a-ros-node-and-a-none-ros-exe/) by [ssasuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/5399/ssasuke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simple answer: In the same way you would do it with any other non-ROS node. It's just an executable that you program. ROS shouldn't limit you as it's just "some other" connection.

The maker of your box should provide such a sample.

That code should be easy to merge with ROS, in either direction, as ROS is basically just a few method calls and does *not* replace your main method.
The only thing to look out for is if there are blocking calls involved.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Samuel Anudeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/4849/samuel-anudeep/) on 2013-10-30**:
Correct me if I'm wrong, but ROS uses TCP underneath right? In that case, wouldn't there be a chance of a port clash?

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-10-31**:
Yep, it does. I know what you mean, but I'm no networking expert. As this is no ROS specific issue the internet might know the answer.